# Show that the value of $\frac{\text{d}^{2r+1}y}{\text{d}x^{2r+1}}$ when $x=0$ is $\frac{1}{2^{2r}}\left(\frac{(2r)!}{r!}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The question originally asks you to prove that if $y=\sin^{-1}(x)+(\sin^{-1}(x))^2$ that: $(1-x^2)y''-x y'$ is independent of $x$. I get that $(1-x^2)y''-x y'=2$ hence proving the first part. The second part asks you prove that for $n>1$ that $$(1-x^2)\frac{\text{d}^{n+2}y}{\text{d}x^{n+2}}-x(2n+1)\frac{\text{d}^{n+1}y}{\text{d}x^{n+1}}-n^2\frac{\text{d}^{n}y}{\text{d}x^{n}}=0$$ 
which again is fine (I did it using [General Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)). The problem I'm having is in the next part, it says show that the value of $\frac{\text{d}^{2r+1}y}{\text{d}x^{2r+1}}$ when $x=0$ is: $$\frac{1}{2^{2r}}\left(\frac{(2r)!}{r!}\right)^2$$

I can't seem to be able to show it, I'm sure it must be something with a double factorial in since it the formula seems very similar to it but I'm not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: You mean $y(x) = \text{arcsin} x+(\text{arcsin} x)^2$, don't you?

Comment: @Dmoreno yeah, the inverse Sine function, I'm never sure of the best way to write it.

Comment: you have a recurrence rule for the derivatives of $y$. I'm pretty sure that you can get a general expression for the $n$-th derivative, and then you can evaluate imposing $n$ odd, that is, $n=2r+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easy since you have the recurrence
$$\left((1-x^2)\frac{\text{d}^{n+2}y}{\text{d}x^{n+2}}-x(2n+1)\frac{\text{d}^{n+1}y}{\text{d}x^{n+1}}-n^2\frac{\text{d}^{n}y}{\text{d}x^{n}}\right)_{x=0}=0.$$
That implies $\frac{\text{d}^{n+2}y}{\text{d}x^{n+2}}=n^2\frac{\text{d}^{n}y}{\text{d}x^{n}}$ at $x=0$. Since $dy/dx|_{x=0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}|_{x=0}+0=1$.
We then have
$$\frac{\text{d}^{2n+1}y}{\text{d}x^{2n+1}}=(2n-1)^2\frac{\text{d}^{2n-1}y}{\text{d}x^{2n-1}}=\ldots\\=((2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1)^2 \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\ldots(2n)}\right)^2=\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\right)^2$$
All are evaluated at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now, the problem I was having was getting from the step where you have the $2n+1$ derivative in terms of the $2n-1$ one and then getting that into a form without a derivative. Just to clarify when you write $\text{d}y/\text{d}x$ is the $+0$ because $[(\arcsin{x})^2]'=2\arcsin{x}\times(1-x^2)^{-1/2}|_{x=0}=0$ Thanks